# Why use React setState updater arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the [React.js documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), when state should be updated based on current state and props, a function should be provided as the first argument to `setState`, as follows:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

In contrast, I have been achieving this like so:

```
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step
});
```

Why is the first method recommended over the second?

Comment: There are circumstances where `this.state` may be stale due to pending state updates. The callback method avoids that by ensuring you are provided the most up-todate state as possible. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:~:text=setState()%20enqueues%20changes%20to,event%20handlers%20and%20server%20responses. Setstate doesn't necessarilly do anything right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State updates that depend upon previous state ***need*** to reference the previous state to update from. With the functional state update you can correctly access previous state.

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state`
> right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied.

With the regular update

```
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step
});
```

Multiple calls to update state *during* the same render cycle will all reference the current state value from the current render cycle, i.e. state hasn't updated yet for any subsequent calls within the cycle. All the updates still occur, however, they each independently overwrite state, so the last update is the one that really updates state.

Consider this demo of regular and functional state updates

```
/**
 * count +3 click handler using naive state updates.
 */
clickHandler1 = () => {
  // assume count equals some number n
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
  // when processed the count will be n + 1
};

/**
 * count +3 click handler using functional state updates.
 */
clickHandler2 = () => {
  // assume count equals some number n
  this.setState((state, props) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })); // update queued, count === n + 0, count = prevCount + 1
  this.setState((state, props) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })); // update queued, count === n + 1, count = prevCount + 1
  this.setState((state, props) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })); // update queued, count === n + 2, count = prevCount + 1
  // now when processed each call uses the result of the previous update
  // count will be n + 1 + 1 + 1, or n + 3
};
```

[image: Edit react - class-based regular and functional state updates]

Answer (score -1):

This doc explains you clearly https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1